# Hibernate one-to-one updating child instead of insering new one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, scala

I have created two classes:

```
class Music {
...
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "music", cascade = Array(CascadeType.ALL), orphanRemoval = true)
@BeanProperty
var uploadedFile: UploadedFile = _
...}
```

and:

```
class UploadedFile{
...
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "MUSIC_ID")
@BeanProperty
var music: Music = _
...}
```

I am creating some UploadedFile instance, Music instance, assigns instance of UploadedFile to Music, and Music to UploadedFile.

Everything is fine now.. Both of them are saved to DB (UploadedFile with foreign key music_id)..

But when I am modifying UploadedFile in the Music instance, and than I am using session.saveOrUpdate(music) hibernate creates new child row with the same music_id (UploadedFile) and updates the Music table row... So I have one row in Music table (correct), and two rows in UploadedFile (incorrect)

Could you help me with that, what should I change?

Greetings,
M.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/music"))
@SessionAttributes(Array("music"))
class MusicAdministrationController extends Logger {

  @Autowired
  @BeanProperty
  var musicManager: MusicService = _

  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/list"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
  def showMusicList(model: ModelMap): ModelAndView = {
    val musicList = musicManager.getAllItems()
    val mav = new ModelAndView("musicList")

    mav addObject("musicList", musicList)
    mav addObject("music", new Music)

    mav
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/add"), method = Array(RequestMethod.POST))
  def addNewMusic(@ModelAttribute music: Music, bindingResult: BindingResult, sessionState: SessionStatus): ModelAndView = {
    if (bindingResult hasErrors) {
      return new ModelAndView("/music/list")
    }

    sessionState isComplete()
    if (music.music_id == 0) {
      music createdBy = "admin"
      music date = new Date

      val file = music.attachFile
      music.uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(new Date, file.getOriginalFilename, file.getBytes, file.getSize,
        FileType.MUSIC, music)

      musicManager.addOrUpdateItem(music)
    } else {
      music modifiedBy = "admin"
      music modifyDate = new Date

      val file = music.attachFile

      if (file.getSize > 0)
        music.uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(new Date, file.getOriginalFilename, file.getBytes, file.getSize,
          FileType.MUSIC, music)

      musicManager addOrUpdateItem music
    }
    new ModelAndView("redirect:/music/list")
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/remove/{id}"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
  def removeMusic(@PathVariable("id") musicId: Int, model: ModelMap): ModelAndView = {
    musicManager deleteItem musicId

    new ModelAndView("redirect:/music/list")
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/edit/{id}"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
  def editMusic(@PathVariable("id") musicId: Int, model: ModelMap): ModelAndView = {
    val mav = new ModelAndView("musicList")
    mav addObject("music", musicManager getItemById musicId)

    mav
  }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your controller code ?

Comment: Ok, so I analized everything and I came with solution..

The problem is here:  
music.uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(new Date, file.getOriginalFilename, file.getBytes, file.getSize,
          FileType.MUSIC, music)

...it creates a new instance of uploadedFile in music, with file_id equal to null... and it seems that hibernate requires that id in child class even for one-to-one (right?)... after adding it, the update works as it should :)